# How to preload typescript class with -r option of ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Suppose there is a file named `lib.ts` with the following content:

```js
export class A {}
console.log('script loaded');
```

Now I start `ts-node` REPL this way: `npx ts-node -r ./lib.ts`
Then I can see it prints "script loaded" which confirms that the script has been processed.

But when I run the following statement in the REPL

```js
const a = new A()
```

It just throws the error `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'A'.`

For some reason I need to preload the class I define in the `lib.ts` but it seems not work well. What was wrong and how to fix it, or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I found is to just assign them to the `global`.

```js
class A {}
class B {}

Object.assign(global, {
  A,
  B,
})

console.log('script loaded');
```